# Quick ASP.NET routing question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

How can I turn this `/Home/About/` into just `/About/` using the rules in the Global.aspx file?

Answer (score 6):

```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
      routes.MapRoute(
          "About", // Route name
          "About", // URL
          new { controller = "Home", action = "About" });

      ...

    }
```

@Scott: Thanks. Fixed it.

Comment: Putting the / at the beginning of the URL will cause an ArgumentException error

Answer (score 3):

```
   routes.MapRoute(
     "About",
     "About",
     new { controller = "Home", action = "About" }
   );
```

Just make sure it is place before the default route handler.

Answer (score 1):

Add a route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "About",
    "About"
     new { controller = "Home", action = "About" });
```

Since it is hardcoded, you want to make sure it is before any routes that have placeholders for the various params.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new route before the default route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("about", "About", new { controller = "YourController", action = "About" });
```

Answer (score 1):

this will give you the explanation too :)
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "HomeActions",
    "{action}",
    new
    {
        controller      = "Home",
        action          = "Index"  // I technically don't think this is required.
    },
    new  // The second object are route constraints
    {
        action          = "Index|FAQ|ContactUs|Examples|Materials|Members" // <-- various actions on my home controller.  Any regex works here.
    });
```